# add a textview on AutoCompleteTextView's element click

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't manage to add a textview when picking an element of an AutoCompleteTextView. Can you  find the problem in this code?

```
 actv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(view.getContext());
                tv.setText("something");
                Log.d("Test","Test");//Works!!
                layout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
                layout.addView(tv);

            }
 });
```

Here is my activity layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@id/global">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="382dp"
    android:layout_height="518dp"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView_aff_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cli_id"
        android:hint="Choisissez un prospect"
        android:ems="10"
        android:text="">
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not setting any layout params to your `TextView`, so basically you're not telling it how it should be displayed. Try something like this:

```
final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));

...
layout.addView(tv);
```

Comment: Hi nKn and thanks, but i still have the same problem, nothing appear.

Comment: I've updated my answer, have a look at it and try changing the `setLayoutParams()` to the line I've just updated.

Comment: I add :  `tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));` but same result.

Comment: See that the class name has changed, now it's not `ViewGroup` but `LinearLayout` instead.

Comment: `tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f));` but nothing appear

Comment: Then the only thing that comes to my mind is that you're passing it the incorrect `Context`. Instead of passing it the `Context` of the `View`, pass it the `Activity`'s or `Fragment`'s context where you're using this code.